# most efficient way to find a sum of two numbers

Tags: python, algorithm

I am looking into a problem: given an arbitrary list, in this case it is [9,15,1,4,2,3,6], find any two numbers that would sum to a given result (in this case 10). What would be the most efficient way to do this? My solution is n<sup>2</sup> in terms of big O notation and even though I have filtered and sorted the numbers I am sure there is a way to do this more efficiently. Thanks in advance

```
myList  = [9,15,1,4,2,3,6]
myList.sort()
result = 10
myList = filter(lambda x:x < result,myList)
total = 0
for i in myList:
    total = total + 1
    for j in myList[total:]:
        if i + j == result:
            print i,j
            break
```

Comment: Tip: don't use standard Python keywords such as `list` for variable names, because it overrides the builtin keywords. Called it `mylist`, or something even more appropriate such as `numbers`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this solution would work....

```
list  = [9,15,1,4,2,3,6]
result = 10
list.sort()
list = filter(lambda x:x < result,list)
myMap = {}

for i in list:
    if i in myMap:
        print myMap[i], i
        break
    myMap[result - i] = i
```

Answer (score 3):

**O(n log n) solution**

Sort your list. For each number `x`, [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) for `S - x` in the list.

**O(n) solution**

For each number `x`, see if you have `S - x` in a hash table. Add `x` to the [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Note that, if your numbers are really small, the hash table can be a simple array where `h[i] = true if i exists in the hash table and false otherwise`.

Comment: Note that the O(n) solution is what Ashwini Chaudhary's answer shows in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary for this and for each item in list look for `total_required - item` in the dictionary. I have used [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) here because a `set` can fail if `total_required - item` is equal to the current item from the list. Overall complexity is `O(N)`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def find_nums(total, seq):
    c = Counter(seq)
    for x in seq:
        rem = total - x
        if rem in c:
            if rem == x and c[rem] > 1:
                return x, rem
            elif rem != x:
                return x, rem
...         
>>> find_nums(2, [1, 1])
(1, 1)
>>> find_nums(2, [1])
>>> find_nums(24, [9,15,1,4,2,3,6])
(9, 15)
>>> find_nums(9, [9,15,1,4,2,3,6])
(3, 6)
```

Comment: Why should we check for c[rem] > 1 ?? It's not obvious. Can you please explain

Comment: @mario23 Without this condition `find_nums(2, [1])` will return `(1, 1)`, we need to differentiate between our current number `x` and `rem`.